# CreateSalesforceObject with Mutli Picklist

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I was under the impression that to create a SF object with a multi picklist in it, you just had to separate out the options with a semicolon.  My current code is:

```
%%[
VAR @email, @fname, @lname, @startdate, @campus

SET @email = RequestParameter("email");
SET @fName = RequestParameter("firstName");
SET @lName = RequestParameter("lastName");
SET @startdate = RequestParameter("startDate");
SET @campus = RequestParameter("campus");
]%%

<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
  var foi = Request.GetFormField("fields");
  var foiArr = foi.split(",");

  var str = "";

  for (var i=0; i<foiArr.length; i++){
   var sfField = foiArr[i]
    str += sfField;
    if (i !== foiArr.length -1) {
      str += ";";
    }
  }

  Write(str);

  Variable.SetValue("@fields", str);
</script>

<!-- CREATE SALESFORCE OBJECT HERE-->
%%[
VAR @id
SET @id = CreateSalesforceObject('Website_Inquiry__c',
 6,
 'First_Name__c', @fname,
 'Last_Name__c', @lname,
 'Email_Address__c', @email,
 'Program_Start__c', @startdate,
 'Campus_of_Interest__c', @campus,
 'Fields_of_Interest__c', @fields)
]%%
```

But this is not working.  Is there a specific way to send multi picklist data to Salesforce?

Comment: Is there an error that you see? Also, can you make sure that the field `Fields_of_Interest__c` is not restricted to accept only certain values defined at the field level on the object, and if it is then does your variable `@fields` consist of the expected values.

Comment: For others: I'm voting to leave this one open. Additional details would help, but the question is narrow in scope and provides the code (well, ampscript) in question. I say let's give OP a chance.

Comment: @DerekF - agreed. I took a stab at this just by looking at the code and to see if providing any details around multi select picklist helps OP here.

Comment: I just get a general 500 error.  I have made sure that the custom field accepts any values put into it, and the @fields variable is expecting a csv string from the form on the previous page.  It is trying to send the information to CRM as "interest1;interest2;interest3;"